# Overriding malloc using the LD_PRELOAD and calls malloc in library functions

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, overriding, ld-preload

I'm creating a small fast app which detects memory leaks in other apps. I use LD_PRELOAD for override default `malloc` and using this stored in the memory every call to `malloc` in your program. Problem is that some library functions of C use `malloc` too. Moreover, there are library functions which don't free allocated memory. Let's demonstrate: 
`MyApp.cpp`

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

static void * (* LT_MALLOC)(size_t) = 0;
static void (* LT_FREE)(void *) = 0;

static void init_malloc ()
{
  char *error;
  *(void **) (&LT_MALLOC) = dlsym (RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");
  dlerror ();
  if ((error = dlerror ()) != NULL)
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", error);
      _exit(1);
    }
}

static void init_free ()
{
  char *error;
  *(void **) (&LT_FREE) = dlsym (RTLD_NEXT, "free");
  dlerror ();
  if ((error = dlerror ()) != NULL)
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", error);
      _exit(1);
    }
}

extern "C"
void * malloc (size_t size) throw ()
{
  if (LT_MALLOC == 0)
    init_malloc ();
  printf ("malloc(%ld) ", size);
  void *p = LT_MALLOC(size);
  printf ("p = %p\n", p);
  return p;
}

extern "C"
void free (void *p) throw ()
{
  if (LT_FREE == 0)
    init_free ();
  printf ("free(%p)\n", p);
  LT_FREE(p);
}
```

And `test.c`. (Assume that a source code is not available initially, and I have a program only.)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (void)
{
  printf ("test start\n");
  int *a = (int *)malloc(3 * sizeof (int));
  if (a)
    printf ("Allocated 3 int - %p\n", a);
  time_t t = time(NULL);
  a[0] = 1;
  printf ("time - %s", ctime(&t));
  printf ("a[0] = %d\n", a[0]);
  free (a);
  printf ("CALL FREE(a)\n");
  printf ("test done\n");
  return 0;
}
```

```
$ g++ -g -fPIC -c MyApp.cpp -o MyApp.o 
$ g++ -g -shared MyApp.o -o MyApp.so -ldl
$ gcc -g test.c -o test
$ export LD_PRELOAD=./MyApp.so
```

Run the program `./test` and see:

```
malloc(72704) p = 0x8aa040
test start
malloc(12) p = 0x6a0c50
Allocated 3 int - 0x6a0c50
free((nil))
malloc(15) p = 0x6a0c70
malloc(552) p = 0x6a0c90
free((nil))
malloc(1014) p = 0x6a0ec0
free(0x6a0c90)
malloc(20) p = 0x6a0c90
malloc(20) p = 0x6a0cb0
malloc(20) p = 0x6a0cd0
malloc(21) p = 0x6a0cf0
malloc(20) p = 0x6a0d10
malloc(20) p = 0x6a0d30
malloc(20) p = 0x6a0d50
malloc(20) p = 0x6a0d70
malloc(21) p = 0x6a0d90
free((nil))
time - Mon Mar 14 18:30:14 2016
a[0] = 1
free(0x6a0c50)
CALL FREE(a)
test done
```

But I want to see:

```
test start
malloc(12) p = 0x6a0c50
Allocated 3 int - 0x6a0c50
time - Mon Mar 14 18:30:14 2016
a[0] = 1
free(0x6a0c50)
CALL FREE(a)
test done
```

I want my app avoid сalls `malloc` in library functions. But I no ideas how to do it. 
Can `malloc` find out which function call it: library or your own? Or can we make to call default not override `malloc` in library functions? Or something else?
P.S. I am sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Why do you not just use valgrind?

Comment: Valgrind not so fast.

Answer (score 1):

I have MANY times used the technique of compiling my code with a macro that replaces `malloc` with my own version. I thought I'd written an answer to demonstrate that, but apparently not. Something like this:

In "debugmalloc.h" or some such:

```
#if DEBUG_MALLOC
#define malloc(x) myTrackingMalloc(x, __FILE__, __LINE__)
#define free(x) myTrackngFree(x, __FILE__, __LINE__)

extern void* myTrackingMalloc(size_t size, const char* file, int line);
extern void myTrackingFree(void* ptr, const char* file, int line);
#endif
```

Then in a source file, e.g "debugmalloc.c":

```
#if DEBUG_MALLOC
void* myTrackingMalloc(size_t size, const char* file, int line)
{
    void *p = malloc(size);
    ... whatever extra stuff you need ... 
    return p;
}

void myTrackingFree(void* ptr, const char* file, int line)
{
    ... some extra code here ... 
    free(ptr);
}
#endif
```

[I allocated some extra bytes by modifying `size` and added then used an offset to return the appropriate actual payload pointer]

This is relatively easy to implement, and doesn't have the drawbacks of injecting using LD_PRELOAD - in particular that you don't need to distinguish between your code and libraries. And of course, you don't need to implement your own malloc.

It does have the slight drawback that it doens't cover `new`, `delete`, nor `strdup` and other library functions that in themselves do memory allocation - you can implement a `new` and `delete` global operator set [don't forget the array versions!], but replacing `strdup` and any other function that may allocate memory is quite a bit of work - and at that point, `valgrind` is probably going to be quicker, even if it runs quite slow.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Dynamic Loader API can help you. There you find the function dladdr() which returns the module and the name of the symbol for a given address, if available.

Please see the man page of dlopen for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In the code posted, you do not track `calloc`, `realloc` and `strdup`. It would be more consistent to track all `malloc` related allocation functions.

You could also track `fopen` and `fclose` to disable `malloc` and `free` tracking during the execution of those.  This would also allow you to track missing `fclose()` calls.

You can do the same for other C library functions that use `malloc`. It is unlikely that `printf` uses `malloc`, but you could track `vfprintf` to filter out any such calls. It is difficult to wrap variadic functions, but the `printf` family all call `vfprintf` or some close cousin, depending on your C library's implementation.  **Be careful to disable `vfprintf` tracking when you call `printf` yourself!**